# Validar tamaño y formato de imágenes desde el servidor en Java

Tags: java, validación, imagen

Hola buen dia ¿saben de una forma de validar el tamaño de imágenes en el servidor con Java?, es un api rest, busque hacerlo desde el cliente pero me di cuenta que es complejo ya que no funciona en todos los navegadores y presenta ciertas fallas así que decidí hacerlo desde el lado del servidor, esta es la entidad

```
 @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "imagen")
    private byte[] imagen;
```

¿Como valido tamaño y formato?. ejemplo que no me deje subir una imagen mayor a 500px * 500px y que solo admita .jp y .png

Gracias de antemano

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de la tabla?la tabla tiene columnas: tamaño y formato?

Comment: ¿te refieres a la tabla de la base de datos?,  este es solo un campo que se llama "imagen" y es de tipo longblob, y lo que puse es como se mapea en java.

Answer (score 2):

tengo el siguiente ejemplo, espero que te sirva:

```
    try{ 
            InputStream is = event.getFile().getInputstream();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(imgdirectory + fileName));  

            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
            BufferedImage scaledImg;
            /*
             *  400 x 450 sería el tamaño recomendable
             */

            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();
            if(width != 400 || height!=450 ){
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Problemas", " El Ancho de la imagen y el alto tienen que ser de 400 x 450 px.");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
                return;
            }
```